# How to resize the PNG file?

Tags: png, jpeg, photoshop

I have a PNG file for banner. I want to resize the banner image to smaller. When i try with paint the resolution is going wrong and the content is not visible clearly. Can anyone please help me on this

[Banner Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tfYh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on Photoshop for Mac or Windows:

1. Go to Menu bar, click Image.
2. Select Image Size.
3. Change width and height.

---

Tip 1: You can also use a shortcut. for Mac: Option + Command + I. For Windows: Shift + Control + I.

Tip 2: In the menu for changing width and height, it is useful to keep the aspect ratio by selecting or unselecting the icon that looks like a chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like Brice Lambson's [Image Resizer](https://www.bricelam.net/ImageResizer/), it's small (less than 200kb), very simple to use, and it resizes images just fine.